# Unexpected value 'MyModule' imported by the Module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, npm, webpack

I am building a library of Angular 2 components that I would like to make use of in other Angular 2 apps via node_modules. When included locally in the test application in my component library, everything runs fine. However, if the library is included as an npm dependency, I get a runtime error of the form:

```
Unexpected value 'MyModule' imported by the Module 'AppModule'
```

Where 'MyModule' is my library module, and AppModule is the top level module of my app.

After a lot of Googling, this particular error is clearly not a rare problem, there are quite a few questions about it right here. I've tried a huge variety of possible fixes and have gotten nowhere. Rather than rehashing individual issues, at this point I'm in search of one clear, illustrative, and *working* (many supposedly working examples found in comments actually fail to build when cloned) example that I might turn into a seed. Ideally the example should:

- Use Angular 2.0.0
- Use webpack 1.x
- Import an Angular2 module and associated components via npm